# Resizing image programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resize an Image C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922040/resize-an-image-c)

How can I programmatically resize an image in C# so that it'll fit in a winforms control?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scaling an image into a PictureBox:

```
class ImageHandling
{
    public static Rectangle GetScaledRectangle(Image img, Rectangle thumbRect)
    {
        if (img.Width < thumbRect.Width && img.Height < thumbRect.Height)
            return new Rectangle(thumbRect.X + ((thumbRect.Width - img.Width) / 2), thumbRect.Y + ((thumbRect.Height - img.Height) / 2), img.Width, img.Height);

        int sourceWidth = img.Width;
        int sourceHeight = img.Height;

        float nPercent = 0;
        float nPercentW = 0;
        float nPercentH = 0;

        nPercentW = ((float)thumbRect.Width / (float)sourceWidth);
        nPercentH = ((float)thumbRect.Height / (float)sourceHeight);

        if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
            nPercent = nPercentH;
        else
            nPercent = nPercentW;

        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

        if (destWidth.Equals(0))
            destWidth = 1;
        if (destHeight.Equals(0))
            destHeight = 1;

        Rectangle retRect = new Rectangle(thumbRect.X, thumbRect.Y, destWidth, destHeight);

        if (retRect.Height < thumbRect.Height)
            retRect.Y = retRect.Y + Convert.ToInt32(((float)thumbRect.Height - (float)retRect.Height) / (float)2);

        if (retRect.Width < thumbRect.Width)
            retRect.X = retRect.X + Convert.ToInt32(((float)thumbRect.Width - (float)retRect.Width) / (float)2);

        return retRect;
    }

    public static Image GetResizedImage(Image img, Rectangle rect)
    {
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b);
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, rect.Width, rect.Height);
        g.Dispose();

        try
        {
            return (Image)b.Clone();
        }
        finally
        {
            b.Dispose();
            b = null;
            g = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And how to use it:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(imageFilePath);
Rectangle newRect = GetScaledRectangle(img, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
pictureBox1.Image = ImageHandling.GetResizedImage(img, newRect);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what does this method solve? Apart from the tight coupling to the Image class, this does not resize a picture, merely provides a way calculate how to maintain the aspect ratio when resizing to defined width and height (tumbRect).

Comment: I'm using this to properly scale images being displayed on a fixed size picturebox, without touching the original file.

Comment: Okay, still, the actual resizing happens in `ImageHandler.GetResizeImage` which is a utility class of yourself I presume?

Answer (score 0):

Sacle and center an ImageBox:

```
private void LoadAndResizeImage(string sImagepath, int iMaxHeight, int iMaxWidth, int iMinX, int iMinY)
{
    int wdt = iMaxWidth;
    int hgt = iMaxHeight;
    int partialX = iMinX;
    int partialY = iMinY;

    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = sImagepath;
    if ((pictureBox1.Image.Height > iMaxHeight) || (pictureBox1.Image.Width > iMaxWidth))
    {
        if ((pictureBox1.Image.Width / iMaxWidth) > (pictureBox1.Image.Height / iMaxHeight))
        {
            wdt = iMaxWidth;
            double ratio = (double)pictureBox1.Image.Height / (double)pictureBox1.Image.Width;
            hgt = (int)(iMaxWidth * ratio);
        }
        else
        {
            hgt = iMaxHeight;
            double ratio = (double)pictureBox1.Image.Width / (double)pictureBox1.Image.Height;
            wdt = (int)(iMaxHeight * ratio);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        hgt = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
        wdt = pictureBox1.Image.Width;
    }
    if (wdt < iMaxWidth)
    {
        partialX = (iMaxWidth - wdt) / 2;
        partialX += iMinX;
    }
    else
    {
        partialX = iMinX;
    }
    if (hgt < iMaxHeight)
    {
        partialY = (iMaxHeight - hgt) / 2;
        partialY += iMinY;
    }
    else
    {
        partialY = iMinY;
    }


    //Set size
    pictureBox1.Height = hgt;
    pictureBox1.Width = wdt;
    pictureBox1.Left = partialX;
    pictureBox1.Top = partialY;
}
```