# How to reduce Image size before uploading to SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to reduce employee picture before uploading. checked for help but the all the answers are very much confusing. And I am here to ask help from experts :)

I am opening image to my picture box through below code

```
OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
dlg.Filter = "JPG Files(*.jpg)|*.jpg|GIF Files(*.gif)|*.gif|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
dlg.Title = "Select Employee Picture";
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
Image im = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName);
picEMP.Image = im;
string imgloc = dlg.FileName.ToString();                    
}
```

and making the image to binary with below codes

```
byte[] img = null;
FileStream fs = new FileStream(imgloc, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                        img = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
```

and finally uploading with a parameter value

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@img", img));
```

But I am not checking image size. I want to check the image size or the resolution(height, width) and reducing image size with a fix size like (188,222) and then upload image to my sql server. My SQL connection code is below:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=host; Initial Catalog=TimeAttendance; User ID=id; Password=password");
```

Please Help .......

Comment: You'll need to use a graphics library such as the GDI+ libraries of .NET to manipulate the image and scale it, etc. [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984108(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Are you trying to make the width and height of the image smaller or do you just want to reduce the number of bytes being stored in SQL?

Comment: @RickS I think the former: "I want to check the image size or the resolution(height, width) and reducing image size with a fix size like (188,222)"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scaling a System.Drawing.Bitmap to a given size while maintaining aspect ratio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442269/scaling-a-system-drawing-bitmap-to-a-given-size-while-maintaining-aspect-ratio)

Comment: All I want to do is decrease the image size so that it block not much then 50kb to my db. currently if I choose an image of 5MB it block the same space so that it takes much time to load. want to remove the size of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried zipping it up and compressing it.  The below library should work pretty well for that.

http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/