# How to set a width and height to a bitmap in c#?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, resize

I have an image and I want to change the width & height of said image.

(For example `Width = 200 Height = 120` and I want to change that to `Width = 30 Height = 50`)

What would be the best way to do so?

[image]

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I upload an image of my code

Comment: @RandomStranger i don't Know what to do

Comment: Give [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442269/scaling-a-system-drawing-bitmap-to-a-given-size-while-maintaining-aspect-ratio) post a read, it might help you. Also, this seems like a question for google. I googled 'c# resize bitmap' and got that as a first result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Bitmap original = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("DSC_0002.jpg");
Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(original,new Size(newWidth,newHeight));
```