# 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

I am getting this error

> System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
>      at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(String filename)
>      at PressRoom.ImageHandler.getResizedImage(String path, Int32 width, Int32 height)

At line

```
byte[] getResizedImage(String path, int width, int height)
{
        if (path!=null)
        {
            Bitmap imgIn = new Bitmap(path); // exception is thrown
            double y = imgIn.Height;
            double x = imgIn.Width;
}
```

How do I handle this exception?

Comment: if (File.Exists(path))

Comment: It did not helped. Still the same error.

Comment: I think your file is not a valid image.

Comment: I have valid image file. when i debug path shows as "\\Images\\Releases\\Penguins.jpg"

Comment: @Hima, and do you have the image in you_exe_dir\Images\Releases\Penguins.jpg?

Comment: Yes it has the image

Comment: just a suggestion: why don't you use the built-in resize functionality? implementation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19565291/562424

Comment: I got the issue. I was passing wrong file path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you surround your code with try-catch?
The exception is usually thrown when the path is not valid, check twice that file exists or the path is in correct format

```
Bitmap imgIn;
try
{
    imgIn = new Bitmap(path);
    double y = imgIn.Height;
    double x = imgIn.Width;
}
catch (ArgumentException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: OP already has the error msg. Your answer doesn't contribute anything towards answering why OP is getting the error.

Comment: @Steve, well the question was "how do I handle the exception", so that's how