# How to compress bitmap to smaller size in C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin

My bitmap is too large for uploading to the printer. I am going to compress it to smaller size so that less data will be transmit over the printer. But I don't want reduce the length and width of the bitmap. I have done some research but all of them require a stream especially as following

```
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.Format.jpeg,50,outputStream);
```

Why do I need a stream to store the file? How can I skip that and get the compressed bitmap that I want? I have tried

```
    originalBitmap = Bitmap.decodeByteArray(imageByteData);
    //Line below not working and got error
    compressedBitmap = Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.Format.jpeg,50,outputStream);
```

In the outputStream which is my Download folder, I did see the compressed image, but how can I access the compressed image again? Unfortunately, the compress method is not that straight forward. My question is how can I compress a bitmap and use the compressed bitmap in another action? Thank you.

Comment: Take a look [at this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19565291/12059568)

Comment: Very unclear. How is _your bitmap too large for uploading to the printer._? Time? Resulting output? Too much data you don't actually need? - Stream or not has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The answer to your question is "use Bitmap.Compress" which you are already doing.  It seems like your core issue is that you don't understand how I/O works in C#.  If you write your compressed bitmap to a filestream, then just open that File to read the resulting output.

Comment: Hi @TaW, my bitmap is almost 3MB, when I debug, the line of the code to send data to the printer takes very long time to be completed before going to next line.

Comment: We couldn't see the details of your code, Could you please post a basic demo so that we can help you better?

Answer (score 0):

You can compress it to an in-memory stream:

```
//Compress to a stream in memory
byte[] compressedData = null;
using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.Format.Jpeg, 50, stream);
    compressedData = stream.ToArray();
}

//load compressed bitmap from memory
using(var stream = new MemoryStream(compressedData))
{
    var compressedBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(stream);
}
```

Comment: Hi Alberto, after executing all the code, why compressedBitmap is null?