# Take a screenshot of each screen separately

Tags: powershell, screenshot, ps1

I'm trying take a screenshot of each of my screens.

Unfortunately, after searching for hours, I've found nothing.

Here is my actual PowerShell script content :

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms,System.Drawing 
$screens = [Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens 
$top    = ($screens.Bounds.Top    ^| Measure-Object -Minimum).Minimum 
$left   = ($screens.Bounds.Left   ^| Measure-Object -Minimum).Minimum 
$width  = ($screens.Bounds.Right  ^| Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum 
$height = ($screens.Bounds.Bottom ^| Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum 
$bounds   = [Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB($left, $top, $width, $height) 
$bmp      = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap ([int]$bounds.width), ([int]$bounds.height) 
$graphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmp) 
$graphics.CopyFromScreen($bounds.Location, [Drawing.Point]::Empty, $bounds.size) 
$bmp.Save("%path%\tmp\Screenshots\%1.png") 
$graphics.Dispose() 
$bmp.Dispose() 
%powershell% -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%path%\librairies\sg.ps1"
```

This takes a screenshot of all of my screens but in one file,
what I would like is to detect the number of screens, and take screenshot of each, for example files named : `Screen1.png`, `Screen2.png`, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over each screen returned by `[Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreen`:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms,System.Drawing 

foreach ($screen in [Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens) {
    $bounds   = $screen.Bounds
    try {
        $bmp      = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap ([int]$bounds.Width), ([int]$bounds.Height) 
        $graphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmp) 
        $graphics.CopyFromScreen($bounds.Location, [Drawing.Point]::Empty, $bounds.Size) 
        $screenName = $screen.DeviceName -replace '^.*\\([^\\]+)$'
        $bmp.Save("$env:PATH\tmp\Screenshots\$screenName.png")
    }
    finally {
        $graphics.Dispose() 
        $bmp.Dispose() 
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, i'm getting a bunch of error !
I tried to solve some but nothing work :

https://pastebin.com/JgfsAufP

Comment: @Dapkz try again

Comment: nevermind, .bounds. were missing ! thanks !

Comment: Yeah exactly, I updated the answer to fix that :)

Comment: Do you have any idea how i can choose the output file size (X, Y)?

i tried something but it just duplicated my screenshot into himself

Comment: @Dapkz Create the `Bitmap` object with the desired size https://stackoverflow.com/a/19565291/712649

Comment: Mmh, that's not really what i'm searching for (and its also complicated to understand since im not doing that much c#), to more explain, i want that the final image is always in 1080p, so it changes width dynamicaly with 1080 in height. This is math to get the width : (1920*[int]$bounds.Height/1080). Now i need to get an output image size of $width,1080

Comment: You have any idea ?

Comment: @Dapkz Not off the top of my head, but I'd suggest searching for C# solutions to the same problem - same underlying API :)