# Resize all images in a directory

Tags: c#

i have to resize image of a directory,

but i am getting error, access denied,
on this line

```
System.IO.File.Delete(_path);
```

i know it is because the image i read is in used, but dont know how to handle it

I have found links on SO, but all are in php :-(

```
for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    try
    {
        string _ImageUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + 
            "Data\\" + dt.Rows[i]["ProductImage"].ToString();

        string _extName = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(_ImageUrl);

        System.Drawing.Image _productImage = ImageReSize(_ImageUrl, 500);
        string _path = _ImageUrl;

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(_path))
        System.IO.File.Delete(_path);

        _productImage.Save(_path);

        _productImage = ImageReSize(_ImageUrl, 85);
        string _strImageName2 = dt.Rows[i]["ProductSmallImage"].ToString();

        _path = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + 
            "Data\\" + _strImageName2;

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(_path))
        System.IO.File.Delete(_path);
        _productImage.Save(_path);
    }
}
```

code of resize

```
 public System.Drawing.Image ImageReSize(string _imageUrl, int Width)
    {
        try
        {
            //uploadImageFile.PostedFile.InputSteam
            System.Drawing.Image oImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(_imageUrl);

            //((oh *nw) / ow)*100

            int Height = ((oImg.Height * Width) / oImg.Width);              // (oImg.Width * Width);
            Size PictureThumbSize = new Size();
            PictureThumbSize.Height = Height;
            PictureThumbSize.Width = Width;
            System.Drawing.Image oThumbNail = new Bitmap(PictureThumbSize.Width, PictureThumbSize.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            Graphics oGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(oThumbNail);

            oGraphic.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

            oGraphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

            oGraphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            Rectangle oRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, PictureThumbSize.Width, PictureThumbSize.Height);

            oGraphic.DrawImage(oImg, oRectangle);
            oImg.Dispose();
            return oThumbNail;
            //oThumbNail.Save(sPhysicalPath + @"\" + newFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Access Denied where? What line? Please help us help you.

Comment: i edited the post, please have a look again, Thanks

Comment: Code of `ImageReSize`?

Comment: What does your `ImageReSize` method do? Can you share some code, especially how you open/close the image files?

Comment: ImageResize code is working fine, if i dont delete the file and save with other name then its working fine, problem is i have to give same name (replace older image)

Comment: Are you sure the image is not `ReadOnly`?

Comment: Yes its not read only

Comment: Does the user account your program is running under have access to the file it is trying to delete?

Comment: when i dint read file and delete simply, its deleted, so i think main problem is its being used some where, i did dispose but its not wroking

Comment: i have given code for resize please check

Answer (score 1):

First you don't have to delete the file before save, the function Image.Save() will replace the existing image but you have to make sure to dispose all handles pointing to the image.
here is an example to explain my point:

```
      var image = new Bitmap("test.png");

      var image2 = resizeImage(image, new Size(48, 48));
      //image.Dispose();
      image2.Save("test.png");
```

Without the dipose you will have an exeption, but if you uncomment the line image.Dispose() it will work like a charm.

for the function resizeImage I copied it for the question [Resize an Image C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922040/resize-an-image-c-sharp)

and here is the code:

```
public static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
{
  return (Image)(new Bitmap(imgToResize, size));
}
```

**EDIT:**

It seems that the Graphics object is the reason, you have to call oGraphic.Dispose();

Call the _productImage.Dispose() after the save.

In fact a more proper way is :

```
  for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    try
    {
      string _ImageUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath +
          "Data\\" + dt.Rows[i]["ProductImage"].ToString();

      string _extName = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(_ImageUrl);

      using (System.Drawing.Image _productImage = ImageReSize(_ImageUrl, 500))
      {
        string _path = _ImageUrl;

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(_path))
          System.IO.File.Delete(_path);

        _productImage.Save(_path);
      }
      using (System.Drawing.Image _productImage = ImageReSize(_ImageUrl, 85))
      {
        string _strImageName2 = dt.Rows[i]["ProductSmallImage"].ToString();

        _path = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath +
            "Data\\" + _strImageName2;

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(_path))
          System.IO.File.Delete(_path);
        _productImage.Save(_path);
      }
    }
    catch
    {
      //Handle the exeption
    }
  }

public System.Drawing.Image ImageReSize(string _imageUrl, int Width)
{

  try
  {
    //uploadImageFile.PostedFile.InputSteam
    using (System.Drawing.Image oImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(_imageUrl))
    //((oh *nw) / ow)*100
    {
      int Height = ((oImg.Height * Width) / oImg.Width);              // (oImg.Width * Width);
      Size PictureThumbSize = new Size();
      PictureThumbSize.Height = Height;
      PictureThumbSize.Width = Width;
      System.Drawing.Image oThumbNail = new Bitmap(PictureThumbSize.Width, PictureThumbSize.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

      using (Graphics oGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(oThumbNail))
      {
        oGraphic.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

        oGraphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

        oGraphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        Rectangle oRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, PictureThumbSize.Width, PictureThumbSize.Height);

        oGraphic.DrawImage(oImg, oRectangle);
      }
      return oThumbNail;
    }
    //oThumbNail.Save(sPhysicalPath + @"\" + newFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
  }
  catch (Exception Ex)
  {
    return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: add oGraphic.Dispose();

Comment: Better yet - use a `using` instead of `Dispose()`

Comment: yeah @dav_i, you have a point since the code like that is bound to have an unexpected outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Call `Dispose` on your Graphics object as well.

Answer (score 0):

Call Dispose on your original image before trying to delete it.

Comment: Yes it did, still same problem