# Is it possible to square an image like this in .NET (without 3rd party tools)?

Tags: .net, image-processing

Is it possible to square and export a JPEG image like this in .NET (without 3rd party tools)?

The method is to extend the canvas (as a white matte) while keeping the image centered and extending the short dimension of the canvas i.e.

if width is 300 and height is 480 then extend the canvas width to be 480.

```
ps = new Photoshop.Application();
ps.Preferences.RulerUnits = PsUnits.psPixels;
Console.WriteLine(f.FullName);
ps.Open(f.FullName);

// unlock background to allow canvas resizing
ps.ActiveDocument.ActiveLayer.name = "From Background";
ps.ActiveDocument.ChangeMode(PsChangeMode.psConvertToRGB);

//  resize canvas to square
double width = ps.ActiveDocument.Width;
double height = ps.ActiveDocument.Height;
if (width > height)
{
    ps.ActiveDocument.ResizeCanvas(width, width, 
        PsAnchorPosition.psMiddleCenter);
}
else if (width < height)
{
    ps.ActiveDocument.ResizeCanvas(height, height, 
        PsAnchorPosition.psMiddleCenter);
}
```

in this before/after i used a gray background in the after image so it is easy to see, but I will use a white matte in prodcution.

[image: BEFORE]

[image: AFTER]

Comment: Putting the code in a GIST means that when the GIST is gone, the question becomes useless to people. From what I can tell you are seeking to crop an image to square around its centre, so maybe just explaining what you want to do in the question would be more use anyway. Have you searched MSDN? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wt4bf7h(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You still need to [edit] and *ask a question*.  It's not clear what you're wanting.  Try adding image examples, as well.

Comment: Yes, it is always better to add code inline. btw I don't understand your question. What do you meany by square an image? To resize an image [refer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922040/resize-an-image-c-sharp)

Comment: means: make the image dimensions square by extending the narrow  dimension of the canvas. If width is 30 and height is 90 then extend the canvas width to be 90px. but if height is 45 and width is 150 then extend the height of the canvas to be 150 (with image in center).

Comment: @will question is in title. I'll move to body of post.

Comment: @glenatron i clarified the question. I thought the script was fairly readable in English but guess not! There is no crop. The canvas is extended instead.

Comment: That is much clearer. I believe the answer to your question is "yes," but I suspect it would be helpful for you to have more detail than that. It's a while since I have worked with .net's graphics stuff, so I probably wouldn't be much help, but basically you will want to create Canvas ( or Graphics or whatever it is called ) of the right size, flood fill it with background then write the image onto it in the right position.