# Set the size of a loaded image

Tags: c#, image, system.drawing

I have the problem setting the size of an Image to a maximum value.
Do you have a code example how to set the Image Size ?

```
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream, true);
```

In the first step I am loading the image from Stream and in the next step i want to set the image.Site.width to 800

Comment: What exactly problem do you have?

Comment: You load image with original size. See [resize image](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1922040/1997232).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resize the image by creating a new Image from it and specifying the size:

```
System.Drawing.Image resizedImage = new Bitmap(image, new Size(100,100));
```

If you want more control over the resize, you can draw it to a new image and set the [interpolation mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.interpolationmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
System.Drawing.Image resizedImage = new Bitmap(100,100);

using (Graphics graphicsHandle = Graphics.FromImage(resizedImage))
{
    graphicsHandle.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    graphicsHandle.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, 100, 100);
}
return resizedImage;
```