# Label Image mode to stretch

Tags: c#, image, winforms, label

I wrote this code to add my `Labels`:

```
JArray a = JArray.Parse(temp);
Label[] labels = new Label[100];
foreach (JObject o in a.Children<JObject>())
{
    foreach (JProperty p in o.Properties())
    {
        string name = p.Name;
        string value = p.Value.ToString();
        if (name == "name")
        {
            labels[counter] = new Label();
            //Image i = Image.FromFile("item.jpg");
            labels[counter].Text = value;
            labels[counter].Image =Image.FromFile("item.jpg");
            //labels[counter].Image
            //labels[counter].BackColor = Color.Blue;
            labels[counter].TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            labels[counter].Top = height;      
            height += 50;
            Controls.Add(labels[counter]);
        }
    }
}
```

The `Image` should stretch to the `Label` Size. How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The abilities to show and manipulate images and text are spread out in a rather wild fashion among `Winforms` controls.

- A `Label` can not stretch its `Image`.
- A `PictureBox` and a `Panel` can but they don't show their `Text`
- A `Button` can do both but will always be a `Button`, no matter how you style it..

So to get a combination you will need to **either** owner-draw something:

- `DrawImage` in an overload to get the right size of the image, then add `Image` to `Label`
- Or `DrawString` the `Text` onto a `Panel` to show it alongside the Image

**or** you could combine two controls with the right abilities:

You can create a `Panel` and set its `BackgroundImage` to your Image and its `BackgroundImageLayout=Stretch`. Then you can add your `Label` with its Text set to the `Panel`'s controls collection:

```
// preparation for testing:
Image image = Image.FromFile("D:\\stop32.png");
Size size = new Size(77, 77);

// create the combined control
// I assume your Label is already there
Panel pan = new Panel();
pan.Size = size;
// or, since the Label has the right size:
pan.Size = label.Size;  // use Clientsize, if borders are involved!
pan.BackgroundImage = image;
pan.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
label.Parent = pan;  // add the Label to the Panel
label.Location = Point.Empty;
label.Text = "TEXT";
label.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

// add to (e.g.) the form
pan.Parent = this;
```

Set Borders as you like..

One more option: **If** all `Images` should have the same Size and if it is `256x256` pixels or less you could add them to an `ImageList`. This will stretch them to the `ImageList.ImageSize` in a very simple way and you can add them to your `Label`..

Answer (score 4):

Very simple:

VB

```
Label1.Image = New Bitmap(Image.FromFile("Screenshot.jpg"), Label1.Size)
```

C#

```
Label1.Image = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile("Screenshot.jpg"), Label1.Size);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WinForms you try try below:

```
labels[counter].Size = 
    new Size(labels[counter].Image.Width, labels[counter].Image.Height);
```

Comment: Jack with your code my label size change to image size,but i want my image size to labels size

Comment: ahh, if you need this other way round then please resize your image before assigning to label.

Comment: how can i resize image?

Comment: Bitmap ResizeBmp(Image.FromFile("item.jpg"), labels[counter].Width,     labels[counter].Height )
{
            Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width, height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
                g.DrawImage(sourceBMP, 0, 0, width, height);
            return result;
 }

Comment: @elnazirani See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922040/resize-an-image-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

This works perfect for me:

- Just set the image in design mode (don't use imagelist) use the "Image" option
- if we have label1 as the label where we want the image, put the next line inside the constructor:

  label1.Image = new Bitmap(label1.Image, label1.Size);

**I was trying the solution of Zibri, but deform the image in my case.**