# Trying to save image after resizing but it is saved black image

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help me in fixing my problem in saving the resized image.
Here is the code:

```
protected void Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    img3.Src = img1.Src;

    img3.Width = Int32.Parse(imgWidth.Text);
    img3.Height = Int32.Parse(imgHeight.Text);

    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Int32.Parse(imgWidth.Text), Int32.Parse(imgHeight.Text));
    Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(b);

    b.Save(Server.MapPath(img1.Src + "resized.png"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line:

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Int32.Parse(imgWidth.Text),Int32.Parse(imgHeight.Text));
```

Constructs an empty image with the selected width and height.
You should use the Bitmap costructor that takes an image and Size parameter

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(yourImage, new Size(yourWidth, yourheight));
```

If you want a high quality resize, check out this answer here:

[Resize an image C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922040/resize-an-image-c-sharp)