# Xamarin.Forms compress image

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to compress jpg images before uploading to server and decompresss images from server for display.

I'm looking for solution for Xamarin.Forms.

I try to GZipStream, but it works with issues. Some images don't decompress and compression effect not enough for me.

Comment: JPG files have a built in compression factor.  You can use a higher compression factor to reduce size, but it's lossy, and you will not be able to recover that data.

Comment: `ImageSharp` is a "pure" CIL approach, https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageSharp A little heavy just to recompress your jpg. Otherwise use a dependency service and use the platform specific jpg compression APIs to reprocess your jpeg with a lower "quality" to reduce the on-disk file size

Comment: I think this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34604217/compress-size-of-image-to-250kb-using-xamarin-forms-without-dependency-service