# rescale region to fit resolution C#

Tags: c#, resize, scale

Here's the problem I'm facing; I'm trying to create a smaller 'window' inside my application but let's say the size of the 'window' is roughly 980x550 and it needs to be rescaled to 880x720. Would I have to create an extra instance and add/remove the distance from the geometry of where I place a dot or is there a quick cut method that can rescale a bitmap?

edit:
**
I should say that what needs to be scaled is a rect, not the image it's self. 
So a dot gets drawn and scaled. Relative to the smaller picture
**

edit 2:

For anyone that comes across this thread, what I ended up doing was using percentages instead of actual positions, that way the position is relative no matter what :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a duplicate of [Resize an Image C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922040/resize-an-image-c-sharp) which has some excellent answers to your "...is there a quick cut method that can rescale a bitmap?" question, although it depends on whether you want to interact with the scaled image (your "where I place a dot" question suggests editing).

Comment: well what I want to do is be able to draw a dot on a smaller image and have it relative on the larger image, but the problem is that the dot is what needs to be scaled, which I should have emphasized. Since what I'm doing is basically making a shader element designer.

Comment: You should still be able to use the routines provided to scale your canvas after every draw operation.  It won't be efficient, but that won't matter unless you want to run it on low-end hardware.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes across this thread, what I ended up doing was using percentages instead of actual positions, that way the position is relative no matter what.

Comment: Just tick your own answer when you can.