# c# - byte array to png file

Tags: c#, arrays, png

In my code I load a 32-bit-depth PNG file (1 pixel 4 byte) into a byte array like this:

```
//Pick a file
OpenFileDialog FileValaszto = new OpenFileDialog();
FileValaszto.ShowDialog();

//Create BitmapImage
BeolvasottKep = new BitmapImage(new Uri(FileValaszto.FileName));

//Create byte array
stride = BeolvasottKep.PixelWidth * 4;
int size = BeolvasottKep.PixelHeight * stride;
MyPixelsArray = new byte[size];
BeolvasottKep.CopyPixels(pixels, stride, 0);
```

After I finish manipulating the pixels in "MyPixelsArray" I  would like to save its data back into a new PNG image file. Only I can't...

I spent more than a day searching the net but there is no solution to this exact problem. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you are trying to resize your image, this link maybe helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922040/resize-an-image-c-sharp

Comment: Can you explain what do you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: What I want to achieve: 1,Load a PNG file into a bytearray (done) 2, Manipulate this byte array thus changing the picture (done) 3, Save this byte array back into a PNG file on the harddrive. (NOT done, hence the question)

Comment: Edit your question and add why you can't. Is it throwing any exception? Does it not compile? Is the result PNG wrong?

Comment: Why not edit the byte of the Bitmap in a LockBits routine??

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but might work.
Try it i hope it help you

```
 //Pick a file
        OpenFileDialog FileValaszto = new OpenFileDialog();
         FileValaszto .ShowDialog();

        //Create BitmapImage
        BeolvasottKep = new BitmapImage(new Uri(FileValaszto.FileName));

        //Create byte array
        stride = BeolvasottKep.PixelWidth * 4;
        int size = BeolvasottKep.PixelHeight * stride;

        MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(stride);
        Image i = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Comment: Then do i.Save('filepath', System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.png);

Comment: Thank you all for your kind help!!! Problem is solved.

Comment: Hi Broadroad,  Could you please mention how you solved? Thanks.