# Large, odd ratio image resize in C#

Tags: c#, image, graphics, resize, interpolation

I have a particular problem that I need help with. I am working with complex proteomics data and one of our plots involves a heatmap of the raw data. These heatmaps I calculate as a raw image that I then resize to fit my chart canvas. The image files that are produced that way are usually very in-balanced when it comes to the width vs height.
Usually, these images are around 10 to a 100 pixels wide and 5000 to 8000 pixels high (this is the size of my raw 2D data array that I have to convert into an image). The target resolution afterwards would be something of 1300 x 600 pixels.

I usually use this function for resizing my image to a target size

```
public static Image Resize(Image img, int width, int height) {
   Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
   Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage((Image)bmp);
   graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
   graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;


   graphic.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
   graphic.Dispose();

   return (Image)bmp;
}
```

This usually works fine for the dimension described above. But now I have a new dataset with the dimensions of 6 x 54343 pixels.
When using the same code on this image the resized image is half blank.

Original Image:
http://files.biognosys.ch/FileSharing/20170427_StackOverflow/raw.png

(the original image does not show properly in most browsers so use "save link as...")

How it should look (using photoshop):
http://files.biognosys.ch/FileSharing/20170427_StackOverflow/photoshop_resize.png

How it looks when I use the code snipped above
http://files.biognosys.ch/FileSharing/20170427_StackOverflow/code_resized.png

Please keep in mind, that this has worked for years without problem for images of 6 x 8000 so I guess I am not doing anything fundamentally wrong here.
It is also important that I have NearestNeighbor interpolation for the resizing so any solution that involves other interpolations that do not result in the "How it should look" image are eventually not useful for me.

Oli

Comment: You might find additional settings for the resize useful. I don't know enough about it myself but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24199315/362432) seems like a thorough answer...

Comment: Nope, first link is not broken. But most browsers have issues showing the image since it is 6 x 54343.
Try "Save Link As"

Comment: oh and, Nope. Crystal ball is wrong. 100% dpi setting. Also, again. It worked fine with 6 x 8000. However, even if that would be the problem I would still need a solution. I can not simply tell our users that they have to change the DPI settings otherwise they can not use the software.

Comment: Oh, also I just saw that the dpi setting would have nothing to do with it at all since the image is generated and resized all in the software. I don't actually ever read or write this image to a drive. So there is not difference in dpi setting between my machine and the machine who created this image because it's always gonna be the same machine.

Comment: This image file is quite the killer poke.  Win10's image viewer refuses to load it completely, simple painting programs like MSPaint or Paint.NET refuse to scroll to the bottom.  It is hitting a bug in the interpolator, it gives up the ghost at 32767 pixels.  I tried to use the WIC graphics library, the next one after GDI+, remarkably it has the exact same bug.  Only workaround I see is to use InterpolationMode.Bilinear, not exactly very desirable with such extreme stretches, or to go shopping for a different library.

Comment: Can you use WPF?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you've hit some legacy limitation from 16-bit Windows era. The obvious way to work it around is to pre-split the source image into smaller chunks using just memory operations and than apply all those chunks with resizing using `Graphics`. This method assumes your source image is `Bitmap` rather than just `Image` but this doesn't seem to be a limitation for you. Here is a sketch of the code:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CopyMemory", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern void CopyMemoryUnmanaged(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, int count);

// in case you can't use P/Invoke, copy via intermediate .Net buffer        
static void CopyMemoryNet(IntPtr dst, IntPtr src, int count)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[count];
    Marshal.Copy(src, buffer, 0, count);
    Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, dst, count);
}

static Image CopyImagePart(Bitmap srcImg, int startH, int endH)
{
    var width = srcImg.Width;
    var height = endH - startH;
    var srcBitmapData = srcImg.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, startH, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, srcImg.PixelFormat);

    var dstImg = new Bitmap(width, height, srcImg.PixelFormat);
    var dstBitmapData = dstImg.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, srcImg.PixelFormat);

    int bytesCount = Math.Abs(srcBitmapData.Stride) * height;
    CopyMemoryUnmanaged(dstBitmapData.Scan0, srcBitmapData.Scan0, bytesCount);
    // in case you can't use P/Invoke, copy via intermediate .Net buffer        
    //CopyMemoryNet(dstBitmapData.Scan0, srcBitmapData.Scan0, bytesCount);

    srcImg.UnlockBits(srcBitmapData);
    dstImg.UnlockBits(dstBitmapData);

    return dstImg;
}


public static Image ResizeInParts(Bitmap srcBmp, int width, int height)
{
    int srcStep = srcBmp.Height;
    int dstStep = height;
    while (srcStep > 30000)
    {
        srcStep /= 2;
        dstStep /= 2;
    }

    var resBmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
    using (Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(resBmp))
    {
        graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
        graphic.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;


        for (int srcTop = 0, dstTop = 0; srcTop < srcBmp.Height; srcTop += srcStep, dstTop += dstStep)
        {
            int srcBottom = srcTop + srcStep;
            int dstH = dstStep;
            if (srcBottom > srcBmp.Height)
            {
                srcBottom = srcBmp.Height;
                dstH = height - dstTop;
            }
            using (var imgPart = CopyImagePart(srcBmp, srcTop, srcBottom))
            {
                graphic.DrawImage(imgPart, 0, dstTop, width, dstH);
            }
        }
    }

    return resBmp;
}
```

Here is what I get for your example image:
[image: resized image]

It is not the same as your `photoshop_resize.png` but is quite similar to your `code_resized.png`

This code can be improved to better handle various "edges" such as cases when `srcBmp.Height` is not even or edges between different parts (pixels on the edges are interpolated using only half of the pixels they should be) but this is not easy to do without assuming some "good" size of both source and resized image or re-implementing interpolation logic yourself. Still this code might already be good enough for your usage given your scaling factors.

Comment: Not quite the answer I hoped for but knowing that it is an inherent 16bit era problem at least explains it. I am very grateful for you code example. Of course I would prefer not having to do the chunk part in order to better represent the edges but that is better then what I have right now. Thank you very much. You deserve the extra points.

Do you know by any chance where the limit is? So that I don't have to do the split operation if not absolutely necessary.

Comment: As @HansPassant pointed out, the true limit should be somewhere around 2^15 i.e. 32767 or 32768. In my code I have 30000 as a rough estimate (and to be on the safe side). Also I'm not sure if your award of the accepted answer is not pre-mature. I'd suggest you to wait and look into other answers. For example, answer by SimonMourier looks promising (I didn't try it)

Comment: I would like to reward the bounty to both of you but since you were the first to provide me with a workable solution you deserve it :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that seems to work. It's based on Windows [WIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee719654.aspx) ("Windows Imaging Component"). It's a native component that Windows (and WPF) uses for all imaging operations.

I have provided a small .NET interop layer for it. It has not all WIC features but it will allow you to load/scale/save a file/stream image. The Scale method has a scaling option similar to the GDI+ one.

It seems to work ok with your sample although the result is not strictly equivalent to the photoshop one. This is how you can use it:

```
using (var bmp = WicBitmapSource.Load("input.png"))
{
    bmp.Scale(1357, 584, WicBitmapInterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor);
    bmp.Save("output.png");
}

...

public enum WicBitmapInterpolationMode
{
    NearestNeighbor = 0,
    Linear = 1,
    Cubic = 2,
    Fant = 3,
    HighQualityCubic = 4,
}

public sealed class WicBitmapSource : IDisposable
{
    private IWICBitmapSource _source;

    private WicBitmapSource(IWICBitmapSource source, Guid format)
    {
        _source = source;
        Format = format;
        Stats();
    }

    public Guid Format { get; }
    public int Width { get; private set; }
    public int Height { get; private set; }
    public double DpiX { get; private set; }
    public double DpiY { get; private set; }

    private void Stats()
    {
        if (_source == null)
        {
            Width = 0;
            Height = 0;
            DpiX = 0;
            DpiY = 0;
            return;
        }

        int w, h;
        _source.GetSize(out w, out h);
        Width = w;
        Height = h;

        double dpix, dpiy;
        _source.GetResolution(out dpix, out dpiy);
        DpiX = dpix;
        DpiY = dpiy;
    }

    private void CheckDisposed()
    {
        if (_source == null)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(null);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~WicBitmapSource()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_source != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_source);
            _source = null;
        }
    }

    public void Save(string filePath)
    {
        Save(filePath, Format, Guid.Empty);
    }

    public void Save(string filePath, Guid pixelFormat)
    {
        Save(filePath, Format, pixelFormat);
    }

    public void Save(string filePath, Guid encoderFormat, Guid pixelFormat)
    {
        if (filePath == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filePath));

        if (encoderFormat == Guid.Empty)
        {
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToLowerInvariant();
            // we support only png & jpg
            if (ext == ".png")
            {
                encoderFormat = new Guid(0x1b7cfaf4, 0x713f, 0x473c, 0xbb, 0xcd, 0x61, 0x37, 0x42, 0x5f, 0xae, 0xaf);
            }
            else if (ext == ".jpeg" || ext == ".jpe" || ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".jfif" || ext == ".exif")
            {
                encoderFormat = new Guid(0x19e4a5aa, 0x5662, 0x4fc5, 0xa0, 0xc0, 0x17, 0x58, 0x02, 0x8e, 0x10, 0x57);
            }
        }

        if (encoderFormat == Guid.Empty)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        using (var file = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
        {
            Save(file, encoderFormat, pixelFormat);
        }
    }

    public void Save(Stream stream)
    {
        Save(stream, Format, Guid.Empty);
    }

    public void Save(Stream stream, Guid pixelFormat)
    {
        Save(stream, Format, pixelFormat);
    }

    public void Save(Stream stream, Guid encoderFormat, Guid pixelFormat)
    {
        if (stream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stream));

        CheckDisposed();
        Save(_source, stream, encoderFormat, pixelFormat, WICBitmapEncoderCacheOption.WICBitmapEncoderNoCache, null);
    }

    public void Scale(int? width, int? height, WicBitmapInterpolationMode mode)
    {
        if (!width.HasValue && !height.HasValue)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        int neww;
        int newh;
        if (width.HasValue && height.HasValue)
        {
            neww = width.Value;
            newh = height.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            int w = Width;
            int h = Height;
            if (w == 0 || h == 0)
                return;

            if (width.HasValue)
            {
                neww = width.Value;
                newh = (width.Value * h) / w;
            }
            else
            {
                newh = height.Value;
                neww = (height.Value * w) / h;
            }
        }

        if (neww <= 0 || newh <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        CheckDisposed();
        _source = Scale(_source, neww, newh, mode);
        Stats();
    }

    // we support only 1-framed files (unlike TIF for example)
    public static WicBitmapSource Load(string filePath)
    {
        if (filePath == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filePath));

        return LoadBitmapSource(filePath, 0, WICDecodeOptions.WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand);
    }

    public static WicBitmapSource Load(Stream stream)
    {
        if (stream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stream));

        return LoadBitmapSource(stream, 0, WICDecodeOptions.WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand);
    }

    private static WicBitmapSource LoadBitmapSource(string filePath, int frameIndex, WICDecodeOptions metadataOptions)
    {
        var wfac = (IWICImagingFactory)new WICImagingFactory();
        IWICBitmapDecoder decoder = null;
        try
        {
            decoder = wfac.CreateDecoderFromFilename(filePath, null, GenericAccessRights.GENERIC_READ, metadataOptions);
            return new WicBitmapSource(decoder.GetFrame(frameIndex), decoder.GetContainerFormat());
        }
        finally
        {
            Release(decoder);
            Release(wfac);
        }
    }

    private static WicBitmapSource LoadBitmapSource(Stream stream, int frameIndex, WICDecodeOptions metadataOptions)
    {
        var wfac = (IWICImagingFactory)new WICImagingFactory();
        IWICBitmapDecoder decoder = null;
        try
        {
            decoder = wfac.CreateDecoderFromStream(new ManagedIStream(stream), null, metadataOptions);
            return new WicBitmapSource(decoder.GetFrame(frameIndex), decoder.GetContainerFormat());
        }
        finally
        {
            Release(decoder);
            Release(wfac);
        }
    }

    private static IWICBitmapScaler Scale(IWICBitmapSource source, int width, int height, WicBitmapInterpolationMode mode)
    {
        var wfac = (IWICImagingFactory)new WICImagingFactory();
        IWICBitmapScaler scaler = null;
        try
        {
            scaler = wfac.CreateBitmapScaler();
            scaler.Initialize(source, width, height, mode);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(source);
            return scaler;
        }
        finally
        {
            Release(wfac);
        }
    }

    private static void Save(IWICBitmapSource source, Stream stream, Guid containerFormat, Guid pixelFormat, WICBitmapEncoderCacheOption cacheOptions, WICRect rect)
    {
        var wfac = (IWICImagingFactory)new WICImagingFactory();
        IWICBitmapEncoder encoder = null;
        IWICBitmapFrameEncode frame = null;
        try
        {
            encoder = wfac.CreateEncoder(containerFormat, null);
            encoder.Initialize(new ManagedIStream(stream), cacheOptions);
            encoder.CreateNewFrame(out frame, IntPtr.Zero);
            frame.Initialize(IntPtr.Zero);

            if (pixelFormat != Guid.Empty)
            {
                frame.SetPixelFormat(pixelFormat);
            }

            frame.WriteSource(source, rect);
            frame.Commit();
            encoder.Commit();
        }
        finally
        {
            Release(frame);
            Release(encoder);
            Release(wfac);
        }
    }

    private static void Release(object obj)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
        }
    }

    [ComImport]
    [Guid("CACAF262-9370-4615-A13B-9F5539DA4C0A")]
    private class WICImagingFactory
    {
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private class WICRect
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
        public int Width;
        public int Height;
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum WICDecodeOptions
    {
        WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand = 0x0,
        WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad = 0x1,
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum WICBitmapEncoderCacheOption
    {
        WICBitmapEncoderCacheInMemory = 0x0,
        WICBitmapEncoderCacheTempFile = 0x1,
        WICBitmapEncoderNoCache = 0x2,
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum GenericAccessRights : uint
    {
        GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000,
        GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000,
        GENERIC_EXECUTE = 0x20000000,
        GENERIC_ALL = 0x10000000,

        GENERIC_READ_WRITE = GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE
    }

    [Guid("ec5ec8a9-c395-4314-9c77-54d7a935ff70"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IWICImagingFactory
    {
        IWICBitmapDecoder CreateDecoderFromFilename([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string wzFilename, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 1)] Guid[] pguidVendor, GenericAccessRights dwDesiredAccess, WICDecodeOptions metadataOptions);
        IWICBitmapDecoder CreateDecoderFromStream(IStream pIStream, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 1)] Guid[] pguidVendor, WICDecodeOptions metadataOptions);

        void NotImpl2();
        void NotImpl3();
        void NotImpl4();

        IWICBitmapEncoder CreateEncoder([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid guidContainerFormat, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 1)] Guid[] pguidVendor);

        void NotImpl6();
        void NotImpl7();

        IWICBitmapScaler CreateBitmapScaler();

        // not fully impl...
    }

    [Guid("00000120-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IWICBitmapSource
    {
        void GetSize(out int puiWidth, out int puiHeight);
        Guid GetPixelFormat();
        void GetResolution(out double pDpiX, out double pDpiY);

        void NotImpl3();
        void NotImpl4();
    }

    [Guid("00000302-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IWICBitmapScaler : IWICBitmapSource
    {
        #region IWICBitmapSource
        new void GetSize(out int puiWidth, out int puiHeight);
        new Guid GetPixelFormat();
        new void GetResolution(out double pDpiX, out double pDpiY);
        new void NotImpl3();
        new void NotImpl4();
        #endregion IWICBitmapSource

        void Initialize(IWICBitmapSource pISource, int uiWidth, int uiHeight, WicBitmapInterpolationMode mode);
    }

    [Guid("9EDDE9E7-8DEE-47ea-99DF-E6FAF2ED44BF"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IWICBitmapDecoder
    {
        void NotImpl0();
        void NotImpl1();

        Guid GetContainerFormat();

        void NotImpl3();
        void NotImpl4();
        void NotImpl5();
        void NotImpl6();
        void NotImpl7();
        void NotImpl8();
        void NotImpl9();

        IWICBitmapFrameDecode GetFrame(int index);
    }

    [Guid("3B16811B-6A43-4ec9-A813-3D930C13B940"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IWICBitmapFrameDecode : IWICBitmapSource
    {
        // not fully impl...
    }

    [Guid("00000103-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IWICBitmapEncoder
    {
        void Initialize(IStream pIStream, WICBitmapEncoderCacheOption cacheOption);
        Guid GetContainerFormat();

        void NotImpl2();
        void NotImpl3();
        void NotImpl4();
        void NotImpl5();
        void NotImpl6();

        void CreateNewFrame(out IWICBitmapFrameEncode ppIFrameEncode, IntPtr encoderOptions);
        void Commit();

        // not fully impl...
    }

    [Guid("00000105-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IWICBitmapFrameEncode
    {
        void Initialize(IntPtr pIEncoderOptions);
        void SetSize(int uiWidth, int uiHeight);
        void SetResolution(double dpiX, double dpiY);
        void SetPixelFormat([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid pPixelFormat);

        void NotImpl4();
        void NotImpl5();
        void NotImpl6();
        void NotImpl7();

        void WriteSource(IWICBitmapSource pIBitmapSource, WICRect prc);
        void Commit();

        // not fully impl...
    }

    private class ManagedIStream : IStream
    {
        private Stream _stream;

        public ManagedIStream(Stream stream)
        {
            _stream = stream;
        }

        public void Read(byte[] buffer, int count, IntPtr pRead)
        {
            int read = _stream.Read(buffer, 0, count);
            if (pRead != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.WriteInt32(pRead, read);
            }
        }

        public void Seek(long offset, int origin, IntPtr newPosition)
        {
            long pos = _stream.Seek(offset, (SeekOrigin)origin);
            if (newPosition != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.WriteInt64(newPosition, pos);
            }
        }

        public void SetSize(long newSize)
        {
            _stream.SetLength(newSize);
        }

        public void Stat(out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STATSTG stg, int flags)
        {
            const int STGTY_STREAM = 2;
            stg = new System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.STATSTG();
            stg.type = STGTY_STREAM;
            stg.cbSize = _stream.Length;
            stg.grfMode = 0;

            if (_stream.CanRead && _stream.CanWrite)
            {
                const int STGM_READWRITE = 0x00000002;
                stg.grfMode |= STGM_READWRITE;
                return;
            }

            if (_stream.CanRead)
            {
                const int STGM_READ = 0x00000000;
                stg.grfMode |= STGM_READ;
                return;
            }

            if (_stream.CanWrite)
            {
                const int STGM_WRITE = 0x00000001;
                stg.grfMode |= STGM_WRITE;
                return;
            }

            throw new IOException();
        }

        public void Write(byte[] buffer, int count, IntPtr written)
        {
            _stream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
            if (written != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.WriteInt32(written, count);
            }
        }

        public void Clone(out IStream ppstm) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        public void Commit(int grfCommitFlags) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        public void CopyTo(IStream pstm, long cb, IntPtr pcbRead, IntPtr pcbWritten) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        public void LockRegion(long libOffset, long cb, int dwLockType) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        public void Revert() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        public void UnlockRegion(long libOffset, long cb, int dwLockType) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```