# C# Webform resize image

Tags: c#, webforms

In WebForm, I use a control Image or ImageButton; is possible to resize an image, according to the ratio, t ? to fit the size of the control, the property Stretch is non-applicable.

If not possible in C# other ways as well JQuery, or javascript?
Ex. the pictures is 1635px x 2048 and the control 332px x 420 ratio 0.79

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize an Image C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922040/resize-an-image-c-sharp)

Comment: Write some code/research?  plenty of .net cropping/resizing controls out there...

Comment: Here i found an Example
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/resize-image-before-uploading1

var thumbImg = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);

// Save the file  
string targetPath = Server.MapPath(@"~\Images\") + FileUpload1.FileName;

// the image is a jpg , but also on Png is same
// on execute i have an exception error
// generic error GDI
thumbImg.Save(targetPath, image.RawFormat);