# C# Aws-Lambda Image Resizing

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I currently have a working C# AWS-Lambda Function working. It is triggered when any file is upload to my S3 bucket.

I am trying to resize images when they hit the S3 bucket. I don't know how to include/reference an image resizing tool.

Is there an AWS Built-in function I can use within my C# AWS-Lambda project in VS2017?

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the C# lambda function when the image is uploaded on S3 bucket. Just pass the image reference to lambda function and somethinge like below code can resize it.

```
public static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
    {
       return (Image)(new Bitmap(imgToResize, size));
    }

    yourImage = resizeImage(yourImage, new Size(50,50));
```

Note: code is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14347746/3196845).