# reduce the size of image to fixed size in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to reduce the the size of an image to fixed size using C# windowsforms.

For suppose am taking an image with size 3 MB , i want the output of the image size is in between 100 to 200 KB.

**Note:** The size of an input image may be vary but i need the output will be the same

Comment: You can reduce image size (width and height) to a smaller image. You can also save it with a new [jpeg compression level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-set-jpeg-compression-level).

Comment: What format are these images in? what pixel format, what size, what have you tried, whats not working, why do you need them a static size

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in functionality to resize an image to a given file size that I am aware of.  The size can be reduced by various methods:

1. Changing to a compressed file format.
2. Shrinking the dimensions of the image.
3. Lowering the quality of the image.

The system would need a loop that attempts to resize the image using one more of the above methods, check what the resulting file size is, and then adjust the parameters and try again until the desired size is reached.

A more common way to deal with this is to shrink the dimensions of the image to a height and width that generally yields acceptable sizes and not worry about the exact size of any one file.  There are numerous 3rd party libraries that will easily do this (I've used ImageResizer successfully), or [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922040/resize-an-image-c-sharp).

Comment: ImageResizer will probably be easiest to use and do the job.