# How to add Background image to adaptive card bot framework

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I'm trying to add background image into Adaptive card. Currently I'm using adaptive card version 1.2 , I have added the image into a folder inside the project. But I'm getting `Could not determine JSON object type for type AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveBackgroundImage` exception.

```
 Uri uri = new System.Uri(@"~\Images\AdaptiveCard_Background.png",UriKind.Relative);
 card.Add(new AdaptiveBackgroundImage() 
 {
    Url = uri
 });
```

Kindly help me in resolving this issue

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56080616/10708483

Answer (score 1):

In your adaptive card, you can add a field "backgroundImage":

Something like this:

```
{
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"backgroundImage":"https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e1/a9/a0/e1a9a0fa5a6d08336e32218f41ab4957.jpg",
"body":[
    // your adaptive card body here
    ],
"actions":[
    // your adaptive card actions here
]
}
```

You can find more adaptive cards samples here: https://adaptivecards.io/samples
Hope that helps.

Comment: You can check on the issue I posted. I have been using Background image in similar way. But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research,I found out that for V4 solution, we need to add Images into a sub folder inside **wwwroot** folder.     In **appsettings.json** file we need to mention the URL where we have hosted the file. If we are running it locally then we need to mention local emulator URL. Get the URL using `IConfiguration`

```
card.BackgroundImage = new Uri(configuration["BaseURI"] + "Images/BlueBackground.png");
```

Hope this helps other who are trying to use images inside card.