# Resize image is losing quality

Tags: java, bufferedimage, resize-image

I'm working with a Base64 Image, and I have to resize that one, the code that I'm using now, in some way is doing this work. But I have notice that I'm losing quality and the image doesn't has the size that I set. I'm not sure what the reason is and how can I fix it.

For example the original image looks like this:

[image]

But after the resize the image lost a lot of quality and the final image looks like this:

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;


public class Base64ImageUtil {
    private static final String JPG = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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";

    /**
     * Decode string to image
     *
     * @param imageString The string to decode
     * @return decoded image
     */
    public static BufferedImage decodeToImage(String imageString) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage image = null;
        byte[] imageByte;
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString);
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
        image = ImageIO.read(bis);
        bis.close();
        return image;
    }

    /**
     * Encode image to string
     *
     * @param imageFile The image to encode
     * @param type      jpeg, bmp, gif, png
     * @return encoded string
     */
    public static String encodeToString(File imageFile, String type) throws IOException {
        String imageString = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
        ImageIO.write(image, type, bos);
        byte[] imageBytes = bos.toByteArray();

        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        imageString = encoder.encode(imageBytes);

        bos.close();
        return imageString;
    }

    /**
     * To make base64 string decoded properly, We need to remove the base64 header from a base64 string.
     *
     * @param base64 The Base64 string of an image.
     * @return Base64 string without header.
     */
    public static String removeBase64Header(String base64) {
        if (base64 == null) return null;
        return base64.trim().replaceFirst("data[:]image[/]([a-z])+;base64,", "");
    }

    /**
     * Get the image type.
     *
     * @param base64 The base64 string of an image.
     * @return jpg, png, gif
     */
    public static String getImageType(String base64) {
        String[] header = base64.split("[;]");
        if (header == null || header.length == 0) return null;
        return header[0].split("[/]")[1];
    }

    public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, int newW, int newH) {
        Image tmp = img.getScaledInstance(newW, newH, Image.SCALE_REPLICATE);
        BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g2d = dimg.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(tmp, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.dispose();

        return dimg;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String base64 = JPG;
        // convert base64 string to image
        String imageString = removeBase64Header(base64);
        String imageType = getImageType(base64);
        BufferedImage image = decodeToImage(imageString);
        File imageFile = File.createTempFile("image", "." + imageType);
        image = resize(image, 600, 800);
        ImageIO.write(image, imageType, imageFile);
        // convert image to base64 string
        String newImageString = encodeToString(imageFile, imageType);
        System.out.println("Image Type -> " + imageType);
        System.out.println(newImageString);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static BufferedImage mat2Img(Mat in)
    {
        BufferedImage out;
        byte[] data = new byte[320 * 240 * (int)in.elemSize()];
        int type;
        in.get(0, 0, data);

        if(in.channels() == 1)
            type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
        else
            type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;

        out = new BufferedImage(320, 240, type);

        out.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, 320, 240, data);
        return out;
    }

}
```

Comment: I found this, do not know if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922040/how-to-resize-an-image-c-sharp

Comment: 1) You are not maintaining the aspect ratio of the image when scaling, there is an obvious stretch on the vertical axis. 2) You're not setting the correct image type so the colors are off, basically `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` should be changed (to what I do not know).

Comment: @JakeHolzinger I believe just using `TYPE_INT_RGB` would be an improvement. Alternatively, `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR`. Both should allow you to store the output as a JPEG with correct colors and no fuss.

Comment: Also, using `Image.getScaledInstance(w, h, Image.SCALE_REPLICATE)` (i.e. "nearest neighbour") is not what you want, if quality is your quest... `SCALE_SMOOTH` or `SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING` is better, but for best results, use a library like imgScalr or a similar, high quality algorithm.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger, thanks it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had done this little change:

```
BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_555_RGB);
```

And use `TYPE_USHORT_555_RGB` it worked for me.