# How to adjust the image size in datagridview cells

Tags: c#

How to Adjust the image size to fit in the *datagridview* cell?
My cell width is 65x65

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.MediumSeaGreen;
    if ((i == 3 && j == 4) || (i == 4 && j == 3)) {
      dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = Properties.Resources.black; //this where I add the image
    }
    if ((i == 4 && j == 4) || (i == 3 && j == 3)) {
      dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = Properties.Resources.white; //this where I add the image
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding, does the `DataGridView` already have the images or you are adding them? If you are adding them, why not resize it before hand before adding it?

Comment: A) It is rarely necessary to loop thru DGV rows to do anything.  Instead use an event such as `RowPrePaint` or `CellFormatting` which is what they are for. B) Never use images from `Resources` that way - it is a factory, not a collection so you are creating a new, unique instance for each row which is wasteful and will lead to a leak.  Store them in an array or image vars and reuse the same one(s) over and over.  Additionally, it would allow you to resize them once ever as mentioned

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922040/how-to-resize-an-image-c-sharp you have several ways to resize an image

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ im just adding them through my code

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp ok im trying it

Comment: @Holger thanks on my way trying it

Comment: Applied formatting.