# Delete all dynamically created panels in a panel

Tags: c#, panel

I have a contact management application (which you helped me a lot to do :D) and on my main form I have a panel called panel_contact. Inside there are panels containing the contacts that are displayed:

[image]

But here's my problem:
When I create a contact, the contact_panel reloads to add the one I just created. For example, in the picture below I added Jackie and you can see that the first contact has duplicated itself, and that's not what I want.

[image]

So how do I delete all the panels in my contact_panel?
I've already tried it:

```
panel_contact.Controls.Clear(); //Don't work
panel1.Invalidate(); //Don't work
```

Anyone have a solution, please?
Thank you.

**EDIT :**
COMPLETE CODE :

```
namespace Contact
{
    public partial class Contact : Form
    {

        List<Personne> contacts = new List<Personne>(); //Contient tous les contacts

        public Contact()
        {
            this.Icon = AppResources.icon;
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Picture_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Ouvre la fenêtre de création de contact
            //Add.cs
            Add ajouterWindow = new Add();
            ajouterWindow.ShowDialog();

            this.Contact_Load(this, null);
        }

        private void Contact_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Création des class contact depuis le fichier txt

            string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"contact.txt");

            try
            {
                List<string> contactsBrut = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();

                string[] inforamtions = new string[15];
                string[] notes = new string[8];

                for (int i = 0; i < contactsBrut.Count; i++)
                {
                    inforamtions = contactsBrut[i].Split('#');

                    for (int z = 0; z < inforamtions.Length; z++) //remplace les valeurs incorrect par null
                    {
                        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inforamtions[z]) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(inforamtions[z]))
                        {
                            inforamtions[z] = null;
                        }
                    }

                    int age = Convert.ToInt32(inforamtions[2]);
                    bool isMan = false;

                    if (inforamtions[4] == "True") {
                        isMan = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        isMan = false;
                    }

                    contacts.Add(new Personne(inforamtions[0], inforamtions[1], age, inforamtions[3], isMan,
                       inforamtions[5], inforamtions[6], inforamtions[7], inforamtions[8], inforamtions[9], inforamtions[10], inforamtions[11],
                       inforamtions[12], inforamtions[13], inforamtions[14], inforamtions[15]));
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erreur avec les données de l'application"); 
            }

            //Afficher les contacts
            if(contacts.Count == 0)
            {
                label_aucunContact.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                label_aucunContact.Hide();

                ClearPanel();
                afficherContact();

            }
            //Continuation du load
        }

        private void afficherContact()
        {
            int x = 4;
            int y = 4;
            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.Count; i++)
            {
                var control = new PersonControl(contacts[i]);
                control.Location = new Point(x, y);
                panel_contact.Controls.Add(control);
                y += control.Height + 2;
            }
        }

        private void Picture_add_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
            tt.SetToolTip(this.picture_add, "Ajouter un contact");
        }

        private void ClearPanel()
        {
            foreach (var control in panel_contact.Controls.OfType<PersonControl>().ToList())
                panel_contact.Controls.Remove(control);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the link to the project :
https://www.mediafire.com/file/sb06mnajgm57vn1/Contact.rar/file

Comment: How do you add a duplicated entry in first place? You must avoid that.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm trying to fix :(

Comment: You need to iterate though the already added `Person` objects and add a new `Person` if doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we continue [your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58674619/how-to-create-dynamically-c-sharp-panels/58675001) with the user control solution, you can write:

```
using System.Linq;

private void ClearPersonControls(Panel panel)
{
  foreach ( var control in panel.Controls.OfType<PersonControl>().ToList() )
    panel.Controls.Remove(control);
}
```

It gets all controls in the panel that are type of `PersonControl`.

We need to create a `List` of the result to avoid collision of references when removing.

Next we do a loop on it and ask the panel to delete each controls.

Usage:

```
private void UpdatePanel(Panel panel)
{
  ClearPersonControls(panel);
  CreatePersonControls(panel);
}
```

Where `CreatePersonControls` is a method containing the code of the previous question to create the display with some `PersonControl`

You can of course put all the code in the `UpdatePanel` method at same time, if not many lines, without creating `Clear` and `Create`. Do how what you feel.

If you need, you can add a refresh, but after seeing your code it is not necessary:

```
panel.Refresh();
```

Comment: Mhh it doesn't work and yes, it's about this project. Maybe I'm misplacing it? I measure it just before the for loop that adds the userControl dynamically :'(

Comment: It's the same code, but with a  function it still doesn't work.

Comment: Strange, can you post some code or a zip with your project folder, please?

Comment: It's okay! It's okay!
I changed the location of the code now all works fine
Thank you very much!

Comment: No, I'm sorry, it still doesn't work. I'll add my complete code

Comment: Can you create a link to a zip containing the project folder as well as a `contact.txt`, please? (You should put the `this.Icon = AppResources.icon;`after `InitializeComponents()` in the constructor)

Comment: Ok, the problem is not with ClearPanel and CreatePanel: the problem is that when you add a new contact you reload the list so the duplicates. To solve that, add `contacts.Clear();` at the beginning of `Contact_Load`. You can also in fact move the `ClearPanel` at the beginning of `afficherContact`. The code in my answer if to have a `UpdatePanel` that call `Clear` and `Create`. But since methods are small you can put the code in only one method at same time. Answer updated.