# mirror compress picture folder

Tags: c#, powershell, filesystems, image-compression

I'm searching the best way to copy folder structure and files of windows filesystem that contains photos and taken it updated.
So I need a mirror structure with reduced size photos to use on web application, but I need to hold on also the original.

I think about using powershell or C# application console and schedule it, but any alternative is appreciated.

Comment: could just use this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922040/how-to-resize-an-image-c-sharp

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but I have another issue, if the image is change on the starting folder, how can I understand if is a new one and so update if the photos are not really the same (Only the name is the same)

Answer (score 0):

You could programatically create the images using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922040/how-to-resize-an-image-c-sharp).

If you are concerned about the data changing and needing to detect this you could either:

Run the script when the image changes. Or keep a log of files modified and if they have been converted. Run when the script runs it could check this and recreate any images that need the conversion.