# Retrieve thumbnail from SVF output using Inventor translator addin

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-inventor

I followed this blog post about Svf generation using Inventor, and I was able to achieve the functionality described in the example.

[Speed up viewable generation when using Design Automation for Inventor](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/speed-viewable-generation-when-using-design-automation-inventor)

Since this workflow skips the use of the Model Derivative API, I am wondering if there is a way to access the thumbnail of my model through the resulting Svf files that come from the Inventor translator output.

I am assuming that it exists somewhere in the output files, but after some searching I haven’t found an obvious way to access it.

I have tried decompressing the gz files in the output directory, but I can not find the thumbnail data in the resulting json files.

[image of svf output files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ7eo.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would say, there is no thumbnail you can access in SVF output. BUT you can ask Inventor to generate it for you. This is how we are doing it https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-configurator-inventor/blob/master/AppBundles/CreateThumbnailPlugin/CreateThumbnailAutomation.cs

```
LogTrace("Processing " + doc.FullFileName);
                dynamic invDoc = doc;

                // TODO: only IAM and IPT are supported now, but it's not validated
                invDoc.ObjectVisibility.AllWorkFeatures = false;
                invDoc.ObjectVisibility.Sketches = false;
                invDoc.ObjectVisibility.Sketches3D = false;

                if (doc.DocumentType == DocumentTypeEnum.kAssemblyDocumentObject)
                {
                    invDoc.ObjectVisibility.WeldmentSymbols = false;
                }

                string fileNameLarge = "thumbnail-large.png";
                string filePathLarge = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), fileNameLarge);


                _inventorApplication.DisplayOptions.Show3DIndicator = false;
                Camera cam = _inventorApplication.TransientObjects.CreateCamera();
                cam.SceneObject = invDoc.ComponentDefinition;
                cam.ViewOrientationType = ViewOrientationTypeEnum.kIsoTopRightViewOrientation;
                cam.Fit();
                cam.ApplyWithoutTransition();

                Color backgroundColor = _inventorApplication.TransientObjects.CreateColor(0xEC, 0xEC, 0xEC, 0.0); // hardcoded. Make as a parameter

                // generate image twice as large, and then downsample it (antialiasing)
                cam.SaveAsBitmap(filePathLarge, ThumbnailSize * 2, ThumbnailSize * 2, backgroundColor, backgroundColor);

                // based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/24199315
                using (var image = Image.FromFile(filePathLarge))
                using (var destImage = new Bitmap(ThumbnailSize, ThumbnailSize))
                {
                    destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

                    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
                    {
                        graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

                        using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
                        {
                            wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
                            var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, ThumbnailSize, ThumbnailSize);
                            graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
                        }
                    }

                    string fileName = "thumbnail.png";
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), fileName);
                    destImage.Save(filePath);

                    LogTrace($"Saved thumbnail as {filePath}");
                }

                System.IO.File.Delete(filePathLarge);
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution will work for me. Appreciate the help!