# How can i resize an image?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Bitmap imgToResize, Size size)
        {
            try
            {
                Bitmap b = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b))
                {
                    g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

                    g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, size.Width, size.Height);
                }

                return b;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

When i call the function for example : ResizeImage(bmp,
How do i set the size ?

Comment: take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1587486/316799

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in example:

```
ResizeImage(bmp, new Size(150, 150));
```